# rebuilding subsonic 2.2

Tags: asp.net, subsonic

I haven't programmed for 2 years so please be gentle in your answers. I'm returning to an old asp.net 2.0 project i wrote a few years ago using subsonic. I can't work out how i got subsonic working in this asp.net project as it is an old version (2.1) and the documentation for 2.x doesn't ring any bells with how I used to have to build the code. Anyhow, I have downloaded subsonic 2.2 and have managed to get that to work so I will use this in the website. However I have seen various webpages saying that subsonic 2.2 requires a very specific version of the mysql data connector (5.2.3 i think) and that I should rebuild subsonic 2.2 with a newer version of the connector.

Questions: is this necessary? If so why? Can't i just use version 5.2.3 of the connector in my website or does asp.net override it with its own version (by the way i generate my DAL in a separate class project and not the website itself)? Can i prevent this from happening? If this is necessary, how do i do it as I really can't remember. Would i just create a new project, add the subsonic source files and the appropriate connector dll and rebuild the subsonic dll or is it more involved than that? Is subsonic 2.2 still supported or am I flogging a dead horse trying to use it?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As you generated your DAL in a separate class project then you should be able use whatever version of the MySQL adapter .dll you like in your web project.

The other option is to use SubCommander program to generate the classes.

I'd strongly advise grabbing the latest version 2.x from https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0 and compiling your own. Failing that if the project isn't too large then maybe look at migrating away? SubSonic was a great tool at the time but there are much better options available now.

Comment: Hello dave - thanks very much for your reply. What could i use instead of subsonic with asp.net 2.0? I have had a look around for alternatives but most of them seem to require newer versions of asp.net